# IdHTTP and IdCookieManager miss one cookie

Tags: delphi, indy, shiro, delphi-2007, indy10

I use TIdHTTP for web-service request, after autentification I must keep session information but IdCookieManager seems lost always one cookie...

This is my very simple snippet

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  Cookie : TIdCookies;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  try
    IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := true;
    IdHTTP1.CookieManager := IdCookieManager1;

    IdHTTP1.Get(Edit2.Text);

    if IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.Count = 0
     then Memo1.Lines.Add('Empty');

    Cookie := IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection;


    for i := 0 to Cookie.Count -1 do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Cookie.Cookies[i].Domain + ': ' + Cookie.Cookies[i].CookieName +
        '=' + Cookie.Cookies[i].Value);

  except
    on E : Exception do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

For example if I do `IdHTTP1.Get('www.google.com');` I get two cookie (1P_JAR,NID), but if I do on a web browser it give three (1P_JAR,NID and CONSENT).

And this is for all URL, It seems like it "loses" always one cookie

Comment: As far as I can tell without more details you cannot compare TIdHTTP (a single request) with browser (possibile multiple) request.

Comment: I'm trying to use TIdHTTP to send web-service request. Before I do that I must login and use session id (stored in cookie) for the following request. But if CookieCollection is empty I can't.

Comment: @MarcoAndreoli You should add some more specific code/service address if you can. Anyhow which versions of delphi/indy are you using?

Comment: The code above is an example, for every web site CookieCollection have a one cookie in less. I use delphi 2007 and Indy 10.6.2.0

Comment: Have you tried Postman instead of a browser?

Comment: I have tried it for you and 2 cookie are returned (1P_JAR and NID). So it's correct, it's not the same behavior of a browser of course.

Comment: When a web browser retrieves a URL, it may end up accessing multiple resources at a time (`GET`'ing HTML, images, prefetching other URLs, etc, even `POST`'ing tracking data back). That is likely where the extra cookies are coming from when you visit `www.google.com`. But with `TIdHTTP`, it accesses only one resource at a time, using whatever cookies belong to that specific resource

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `TIdCookieManager` might not keep every cookie it receives. If a cookie is malformed or expired, or if `TIdCookieManager.OnNewCookie` returns False, then the cookie is ignored. And also note that `TIdCookieManager` might not send back every cookie it keeps. If a given cookie does not match the URL being requested, the cookie will not be sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare a single GET request response to a browser response. It's not the same thing.

If you use e.g. [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) you will get the very same result (2 cookies for www.google.com).

I think you should modify the service server side if you are in control of it or consume it in a different way if you are not.

Comment: Ok, you are right (I also try with Insomnia). But my problem still remain, I must have the cookie of the session for doing other ws request. My back-end is managed by Apache Shiro framework, probably I must search the problem on that

Comment: You first should look at @RemyLebeau comments to your original question. Answering to your question without further specific details is not simple, but you can integrate a web browser (TWebBrowser or TChromium for example) and let it do the dirty work; you can then inspect cookies via javascript ´document.cookie'. Again, this is just an abstract example, without further details I can't be more specific.

Comment: Anyway, I think your question is solved, you should ask another question 'cause this one was about a TIdHTTP misunderstanding.